# How can I databind a non-command MenuItem IsEnabled to stay consistent with a command based MenuItem?

Tags: wpf, binding

This menuItem because it's linked to a command does the magic behind the scenes for me:

```
 <MenuItem Name="mnuOpen"  Command="Open"/>
```

where I have

```
    <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Open"
                    Executed="CommandBinding_Open_Executed"
                    CanExecute="CommandBinding_ProjectSelected"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
```

but every binding I've tried has failed to do anything.

```
<MenuItem Name="mnuExplorer" Click="mnuExplorer_Click" Header="Open Containing Folder" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=mnuOpen, Path=IsEnabled}" />
```

Comment: Im not sure if i get you right but it works fine

Answer (score 1):

It works fine maybe you forgot to set CanExecute flag or have other dependency

full code

```
<Window x:Class="MenuBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Open"
                Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"
                CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Grid>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Name="mnuOpen"  Command="Open" IsEnabled="False" />
        <MenuItem Name="mnuExplorer" Header="Open Containing Folder" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=mnuOpen, Path=IsEnabled}" />
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

and class

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Magic");
    }

    private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true; //define if command can be executed
    }
}
```

Comment: After adding your attribute `IsEnabled="False"` to the `mnuOpen`, now it's not enabling ever. Taking it back out and I return to `mnuExplorer` not being disabled initially before `mnuOpen`'s conditions are met to enable it.